# Error launch Weblogic in JDeveloper

Tags: oracle, windows10, weblogic, jdeveloper

he instalado Oracle SOA suite 12 en un equipo Windows 10. Al tratar de arrancar el weblogic integrado en JDeveloper obtengo el siquiente error:

```
[Waiting for the domain to finish building...]
[03:00:49 PM] IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain is invalid.  Regenerating it...
[03:00:49 PM] Creating IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain...
[03:00:49 PM] ERROR:  An error occurred while building the default domain.
Please see this log file for more details:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
The Server Instance cannot be started because the IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain was not built successfully.</code>
```

Este es el contenido del log que se indica en el error:

```
Adding environment variable to WLST script USER_MEM_ARGS = -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m

Log File:  

    C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_PT.12.2.1.4.0_GENERIC_190911.2248.S
Product Home:  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2019-10-29 15:04:38

cmd.exe /c ""C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.wlst.ScriptRunnerImpl.runScript(ScriptRunnerImpl.java:106)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DomainScriptRunnerImpl.runScript(DomainScriptRunnerImpl.java:146)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder.createDomain(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:606)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder.build(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:274)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.adrs.weblogic.builder.DefaultDomainBuilder$1.run(DefaultDomainBuilder.java:225)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py"
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.needsEscaping(ProcessImpl.java:279)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.createCommandLine(ProcessImpl.java:202)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:436)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 9 more
```

Alguien sabe cuál puede ser la causa del error y cómo puede solucionarse?

Comment: El problema fue el expuesto por Alfabravo y se resolvió con los parámetros de arranque de la JVM que indicó. También probé a instalar jdk11 y otras versiones de jdk8 pero no solucionaron el problema.
Siento dar feedback tan tarde sobre el problema que planteé y que además tenga que hacerlo desde otra cuenta. Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

Hay una posible regresión en la última actualización y parece interpretar diferente los parámetros.

Puedes añadir a los parámetros de arranque de la JVM: `-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true`

[respuesta en SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58484737/236345)

[notas de versión Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/13-0-1-relnotes-5592797.html#JDK-8221858)

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el problema es de la nueva versión del JDK, volví a instalar esta vez utilizando el JDK 1.8.0_221 en vez del 1.8.0_231, eso lo resolvió.

Answer (score 0):

Solucion:

O.S Windows:

1-buscar la ruta de instalacion:
en mi caso:

C:\Oracle\Middleware\JDevHome\jdeveloper\ide\bin

ubicar el archivo ide.conf

abrir y agregar la siguiente linea:

AddVMOption  -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true

[image: Solucion Malformed argument has embedded quote jdev 12.2.1.4]